# читаются малая часть qr кодов на pythone 3

Tags: python-3.x, cv2

```
file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)
            downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
            src = 'C:/Users/KOLYA/PycharmProjects/k ege/' + '1.png'
            with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
                new_file.write(downloaded_file)
            img=cv2.imread('1.png')
            detector=cv2.QRCodeDetector()
            data, bbox, clear_qrcode = detector.detectAndDecode(img)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, data)

            cv2.waitKey(0)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

огромное количество qr кодов которые сфоткал и отправил боту просто выдают ошибку как сделать чтобы на фотографиях находило qr коды и их можно было расшифровать
p.s не судите строго я ничего не знаю решил открыть для себя что-то новое, но не все получается реализовать в должном виде

Comment: какую ошибку? есть пример фото что не распознались?

Comment: у меня состоит конструкция из try except и ошибка присылается в телеграмм, а ошибки не одинаковые 1)A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message text is empty. 2)OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'